# A specific Arabic word in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic

I need to replace a specific Arabic word from a string, such as, `صح` with any variations of white space characters before or after it. I use the following regex:

```
/\s*(صح)\s*/
```

It works fine on [Regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ9pI5/1). However, this regex seems to be not functional in Javascript code like the following:

```
txt1 = txt.replace(/\s*(صح)\s*/ig,inpt)
```

I have tried to use a RegExp object like:

```
f = "/\s*(صح)\s*/ig"
r = new RegExp(f)
txt1 = txt1.replace(r,inpt);
```

Finally, I knew that Javascript RegEx does not read Unicode characters, I tried to decode the word `صح` to be `f = "/\s*(u\1589-u\1581)\s*/i"` but also no result. Here I'm not asking about character's class. I just meant by a specific word(s).

**Edit**

The using of `r` snipet:

```
txt1 = txt.replace(' صح',inpt);
     if (txt1 == txt){
       f = "/\s*(صح)\s*/ig"
       r = new RegExp(f)
       txt1 = txt1.replace(r,inpt);

     }
```

Comment: `Finally, I knew that Javascript RegEx does not read Unicode characters` It does recognize Unicode character in Basic Multilingual Plane. Just that for astral plane characters (code points from U+10000), JavaScript represent them as 2 UTF-16 code units, so the regex to match them will be a bit messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RegExp syntax is wrong in the edited snippet

```
f = /صح/gi //no quotes
r = new RegExp(f)
txt1 = 'صحasdf'.replace(r,'!');
```

This works as expected. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Wow, I **noticed that**, using my orginal regex `/\s*(صح)\s*/ig` just without quotes as you regarded, solves the issue. Thanks

Comment: Why not just `'صحasdf'.replace(/صح/gi,'!');`? There is no need to create new RegExp object.

Comment: There isn't. The only advantage I can think of is creating a regex based on variables.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
/\s*(صح)\s*/ig // is not the same as new RegExp("/\s*(صح)\s*/ig")
// it is, however, the same as
new RegExp("\\s*(صح)\\s*", "ig")
```

and as long as you don't touch the surrounding whitespace, you'll be all good. Though, I don't know how whitespace matters in Arabic, so I'm assuming there are extenuating circumstances (maybe it's like `\b`):

This should do it:

```
yournewstring = 'something' // or whatever 
f = /(\s*)صح(\s*)/gi // capture the whitespace 
r = new RegExp(f)

// put the whitespace back
txt1 = 'test صح   string'.replace(r,'$1'+yournewstring+'$2');
```

Comment: Awesome  ,  